# jquery Datepicker code

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, shopify

I'm wondering if anyone can help me troubleshoot my jquery datepicker code.
I changed themes in shopify and now this datepicker doesn't come up with the calendar view. It just has a text box for text (not even dates). Thank you!

```
{{ 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js' | script_tag }}

<div style="width:300px; clear:both;">
  <p>
    <label for="date{{i}}">Delivery Date of {{ item.title }} (Please allow at least 2 days for delivery):</label>
    <input id="date{{i}}" type="text" name="attributes[date{{i}}]" value="{{ cart.attributes.date }}" onkeyup="d_date.value=this.value" class="required" data-error="Please tell us which date you want your delivery for" />
    <input type="hidden" id="d_date" name="properties[date]" />
    <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> </span>
  </p>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function() { 
  jQuery("#date{{i}}").val("").datepicker({ minDate: 2,                     
        beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,

                numberOfMonths: 1,

                minDate: 2,

                maxDate: '+2M',

                firstDay: 7

      });

      function noSunday(date){
          var day = date.getDay();
                      return [(day > 0), ''];
      }; 
  function nonWorkingDates(date) {

                var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;

                var closedDates = [[1, 1, 2014], [12, 25, 2013]];

                var closedDays = [[Saturday], [Sunday]];



                for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {

                    if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {

                        return [false];

                    }

                }



                for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {

                    if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&

                        date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&

                        date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {

                        return [false];

                    }

                }



                return [true];

            }


  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It displays a datepicker when you click inside the text field. If you don't want the text field at all, you could [display the datepicker inline](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline). Perhaps you could provide a screenshot or a link to a demo site showing the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Steph.
I finally discovered through a lot of questions that the theme I was using in Shopify does not support the date picker in the product pages. I have no idea why that is. It does support a date picker snippet. Only, not on each product page.